# Giving Starbases advanced warning

Tags: artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator

**What is the effect of having the Comms station advise Starbases of your imminent arrival beforehand?**

What is the benefit of informing allied starbases that you will be arriving soon?  Does it improve the speed at which they will refill and repair your ship?  What is the timing window you have to take advantage of this benefit, if any, after calling?  Is there any consequence for giving them such notice and ending up not arriving in a timely manner (or at all)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Manual PDF:

The Captain of the space ship Perth instructs the Comms Officer to request docking with Deep Space Station 3, which has a load of Type 6 Mines ready. Although the Helm Officer will initiate the docking procedure, Comms has the ability to double the rate of loading and unloading for 30 seconds by alerting the station of your impending arrival (that is, once Comms requests docking, the rate will be doubled for the next 30 seconds). To initiate any message, the Comms Officer clicks the Transmit button:

I believe the bonus times out if you don't reach the station in a reasonable period of time.
There is no penalty for not calling ahead, Just a bonus for doing so.

Comment: Whether it is a "bonus" or "penalty" is all about perspective, really.  If doing something results in a bonus, you could just as easily say that not doing it is a penalty.  The real question about a "penalty," though, is whether there is a detriment to contacting them without arriving or doing so too often.